# How to change the height of the separator in UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This question has been around for a while, but this is a slightly different variation. I want to increase the height of the separator in the UITableView so it REALLY increases the height and doesn't just take up space within the cell. I am also putting a radius on the cell as well.

The code I have to customise the cell is below. I have also tried a variant in cellForRowAtindexPath adding a view to each cell, which has the same effect. They only take up space within the cell, rather than replacing the separator with a new view.

I want the space between the cells to be 20pt and clear color.... is this possible?

```
class CustomTVC: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    let mScreenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let mSeparatorHeight = CGFloat(20.0) // Change height of speatator as you want
    let mAddSeparator = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - mSeparatorHeight, width: mScreenSize.width, height: mSeparatorHeight))
    mAddSeparator.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange // Change backgroundColor of separator
    self.addSubview(mAddSeparator)

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // THIS ADDS THE CORNER RADIUS
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we usually do is embed cell's subviews in a view and constrain this view so that it is 10px from top and bottom of the contentview. Make sure to se tableView's backgound color to .clear.